# Link images to themselves wordpress

Tags: image, wordpress, hyperlink

I have aroung 6k posts with images and now I need to link all them to the source image (to open them with pretty photo and make them "responsive") there are no custom fields with src links, simply html code with src.

Any suggestion in how to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a javascript code that you embed in your template. This code looks for all images in the post content and modifies them as wanted. With jQuery something like that:

```
$("img").attr("src", function() {
    return "/resources/" + this.title;
});
```

- taken from the [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-functionindex--attr)

The down-side of that is that this script has to run everytime the post is requested again. The alternative option would be to write a php script to replace all links in the database once. That is probably more effort at first but in my opinion worth it since its a one time job.

Comment: Yup, I wa thinking what's better... and still thinking in which is the best way, I'm gona test the jquery "patchword" and see how the site works (: thanks for that suggestion!